# Match the first n characters after a string is matched in a log file with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a line like this in a log file:

> 2015 Apr 24 00:13:22 (notice) sudo: mailwall : TTY=unknown;
>   PWD=/data/scanner/jobs/bmagent ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/yum -d 1 -c
>   /data/yum/etc/yum.conf --get-desc --check-only install sms-appliance-
>   release-10.5.2-3 accepted password for support

I need to search for lines ending in `"accepted password for support"` and return the timestamp at the beginning of those lines, eg `"2015 Apr 24 00:13:22"`

I got as far as this regex:

```
(\b.*)(?=\baccepted\b.\bpassword\b.\bfor\b.\bsupport\b)
```

It returns the entire line. I want only the first 20 characters (the timestamp).

How can I change my regex?

Comment: FYI, (\b.{0,20})(?=\baccepted\b.\bpassword\b.\bfor\b.\bsupport\b) is returning "-release-10.5.2-3"

Comment: What is the environment/language? Does the string contain newline symbols?

Comment: Language is C# and the the line I mentioned above is present inside a log file. Just before the start of the above line there is newline and also there is one after the line, basically it is a log file delimited by newlines.

Comment: Thanks #Kasra for the nice edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what you supplied in the comments, in C# you do not need to use a regex at all for this task.

```
var result2 = txt.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
         .Where(p => p.Trim().EndsWith("accepted password for support") && p.Length > 19)
         .FirstOrDefault().Substring(0, 20);
```

[image]

Or, a regex solution:

```
var txt = "\r\n2015 Apr 24 00:13:22 (notice) sudo: mailwall : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/data/scanner/jobs/bmagent ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/yum -d 1 -c /data/yum/etc/yum.conf --get-desc --check-only install sms-appliance-release-10.5.2-3 accepted password for support\r\nOne more line";
var rgx = new Regex(@"(?m)^\d{4}\s+\p{L}{3}\s+\d{1,2}\s+\d{2}(?::\d{2}){2}(?=.*?\baccepted\s+password\s+for\s+support\b)");
var result = rgx.Match(txt).Value;
```

[image]

Actually, @Bohemian regex [also works](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3Fm)%5E.%7B20%7D(%3F%3D.*accepted%20password%20for%20support%5Cr%3F%24)&i=%0D%0A2015%20Apr%2024%2000%3A13%3A22%20(notice)%20sudo%3A%20mailwall%20%3A%20TTY%3Dunknown%20%3B%20PWD%3D%2Fdata%2Fscanner%2Fjobs%2Fbmagent%20%3B%20USER%3Droot%20%3B%20COMMAND%3D%2Fusr%2Fbin%2Fyum%20-d%201%20-c%20%2Fdata%2Fyum%2Fetc%2Fyum.conf%20--get-desc%20--check-only%20install%20sms-appliance-release-10.5.2-3%20accepted%20password%20for%20support%0D%0AOne%20more%20line), you just need to specify the `RegexOptions.Multiline` flag, or use `(?m)` inline option at the beginning of the pattern.

**What is *MULTILINE* option?**

`(?m)` inline option forces `^` and `$` in the pattern that is to the right of this option match the start and end of the **line**, not the whole string. The difference of `(?m)` and `RegexOptions.Multiline` is that the latter is set for the whole pattern, and the inline variant can be set for a part of the pattern.

Comment: See my regex demo on [Regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3fm)%5e%5cd%7b4%7d%5cs%2b%5cp%7bL%7d%7b3%7d%5cs%2b%5cd%7b1%2c2%7d%5cs%2b%5cd%7b2%7d(%3f%3a%3a%5cd%7b2%7d)%7b2%7d(%3f%3d.*%3f%5cbaccepted%5cs%2bpassword%5cs%2bfor%5cs%2bsupport%5cb)&i=%0d%0a2015+Apr+24+00%3a13%3a22+(notice)+sudo%3a+mailwall+%3a+TTY%3dunknown+%3b+PWD%3d%2fdata%2fscanner%2fjobs%2fbmagent+%3b+USER%3droot+%3b+COMMAND%3d%2fusr%2fbin%2fyum+-d+1+-c+%2fdata%2fyum%2fetc%2fyum.conf+--get-desc+--check-only+install+sms-appliance-release-10.5.2-3+accepted+password+for+support%0d%0aOne+more+line).

Comment: Does it work for you? Please let me know if you need futher assistance.

Comment: Aha....  Likes for (?m)... The final expression which is working in Expresso,  Regexstorm.net and everywhere is : 
(?m)(^.{0,20})(?=.*\baccepted\s+password\s+for\s+support\b)

Comment: `(?m)` inline option forces `^` and `$` in the pattern that is to the right of this option match the start and end of the **line**, not the whole string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80032/discussion-between-prasath-govind-and-stribizhev).

Answer (score 1):

Try a match anchored to start and a look ahead:

```
^.{20}(?=.*accepted password for support$)
```

See l[ive demo](http://rubular.com/r/C5hlnsCNqt).

---

If you can't use look aheads, try group 1 of:

```
^(.{20}).*accepted password for support$
```

Comment: It is not working! :( I have also tried
(^.{20})(?=.*accepted password for support$)
and (^.{20})(?=\baccepted\b.\bpassword\b.\bfor\b.\bsupport\b)

Comment: @pra the regex works (see link). Maybe your language/tool doesn't understand look aheads. See edit for alternative

Comment: @PrasathGovind There is nothing wrong with the regex, so it must be something in how you are using it.  The parentheses around the regexes in your comment look vaguely suspicious, but should by themselves be harmless.  But so this begs the question, how are you using this regex?

Comment: I have pasted the content of the log file to the Expresso tool and then I play with regexs which gives me the output if the match is found

Comment: @PrasathGovind: You can also use very nice Web sites like [Regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester) and [regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester) to test your regexes.